# Regex to replace decimal and integer strings with numbers

Tags: regex, sublimetext

In sublime text I have some data that contains numeric strings. Some are decimals and others are integers. I would like to remove the quotes to have them just as numbers. Is there a regular expression I can use to achieve this. I would also need a `replace` expression to go with it.

E.g.

```
'0'    => 0
'1'    => 1
'1234' => 1234
'1.23' => 1.23
```

I've extensively searched for a solution with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work: `'(\d+(\.\d+)?)'`. This will capture the number and place it in a group. You can then replace that with either `$1` or `\1`. This should backreference the matched group, which is the number itself.

Regex explanation available [here](http://regex101.com/r/fK7qY3).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @npinti's answer;

If you need to work with negative integers as well; in **SublimeText**

`Ctrl+H` Find & Replace

**Find**: `'((\-)?\d+(\.\d+)?)'`

`Alt+R` Find (search) using regular expressions

**Replace**: `\1`

**Illustration...**

[image: Illustartion]

**Regex tested with [Regex101](https://regex101.com)**

[image: Integer - Regex Pattern]